# How to convert the particular date to the am/pm format?

Tags: objective-c, nsdateformatter

I have got a particular date from the string 
 NSString *str = @"2016-05-04 08:42:00 +0000";
And i want to convert this into 08:42 AM format.
Here is my code

```
NSString *str = @"2016-05-04 08:42:00 +0000";// put here item.TimeStart

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter1 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] ;
[dateFormatter1 setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMM YYYY HH:mm:ss VVVV"];// here give the format which you get in TimeStart

NSDate *date1 = [dateFormatter1 dateFromString: str];

dateFormatter1 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] ;
[dateFormatter1 setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a"];

NSString *convertedString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date1];
NSLog(@"Converted String : %@",convertedString);
```

But this is returning nil in Converted String. Why ?? Any idea??

Comment: `dateFormat` of `dateFormatter1` does not match the format of `str`. If you debug, you'll see that `date1` is nil. So it points out that your issue is on the first date formatter `dateFormatter1`, and the reste of the code is irrelevant until you fix that.

Comment: yeah @Larme date1 is nil . Is the dateFormatter [dateFormatter1 setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMM YYYY HH:mm:ss VVVV"] correct?

Comment: Yeahh i found it i replaced the dateformatter with "YYYY-dd-MM HH:mm:ss VVVV"" but i am getting 2:21 PM in log. Why so?

Comment: No. I said that is not. Understand what means a dateFormat and do no copy/paste a format you saw on the web. You clearly see that you `str` start with the year. So at least, you format should start with "yyyy". Then you have the month (and between a "-"). So your format you do "yyyy-MM", and so on. Just write `2016-05-04 08:42:00 +0000` on a line in a text editor, then write your format and each part has to be in the same order.

Comment: Log `date1`, and I guess that you are in a +6:30 timeZone. You are missing in the second format the timeZone to render.

Comment: 2016-05-04 08:42:00 +0000 in date1 log. How to adjust the time zone??

Comment: `[dateFormatter1 setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]]`?

Comment: Still it is 2:21 PM after setting the timeZone. Please help.

Comment: Your original time is in UTC - "+0000". You need to set the timezone of your second for matter to UTC or it will default to your local timezone.

Comment: @CRD can you please say to do how?

Comment: You already know how to set the timezone, so I'm not sue what you are asking. Read the examples in the [`NSDateFormatter` docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSDateFormatter/dateFormat). Also to parse the original timezone you want the 'x'  or 'Z' formats not 'V' - [see docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSDateFormatter/dateFormat).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add the following line to set the time zone time difference to 0 and you will get the actual time.

```
        //Add this line to set the time zone time difference to 0
        dateFormatter1.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0];
```

After adding this, Your final code will look line as follows:

```
    NSString *str = @"2016-05-04 08:42:00 +0000";

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter1 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] ;
    [dateFormatter1 setDateFormat:@"YYYY-dd-MM HH:mm:ss VVVV"];

    NSDate *date1 = [dateFormatter1 dateFromString: str];

    dateFormatter1 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

    //Add this line to set the time zone time difference to 0
    dateFormatter1.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0];

    [dateFormatter1 setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a"];

    NSString *convertedString = [dateFormatter1 stringFromDate:date1];
    NSLog(@"Converted String : %@",convertedString);
```

Comment: @ Microprocessor8085 thanks... hey have you got working idea in watchconnectivity?? Sorry i can't ask question any more.. SO denied my asking facility

Comment: @ChelseaShawra Hey! Sorry, I have no idea about WatchKit.

Comment: @ChelseaShawra yeah, why not.

Answer (score 0):

It will help you

```
   -(NSDate *)calculateDate:(NSString *)getString
    {

        NSDateFormatter *Format = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [Format setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"];

        NSDate *aDate = [Format dateFromString:getString];

        if( !aDate )
        {
            [Format setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss a"];
            [Format setLocale:[NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"]];
            aDate = [Format dateFromString:getString];
        }

        return aDate;
    }
```

When we have a string like 2001-02-15T13:25:00 and we want to format it to 12H format, we just need to define the local.